# Issues passing data from the UI into a database - JSF, JPA, etc

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

im having a bit of an issue trying to pass the value entered in the u.i. to a specific table and column in the database, however when i submit this value to be passed i get the error

```
WARNING:   #{markingBean.markSectionOne}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{markingBean.markSectionOne}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

in the glassfish console

i am using netbeans, jsf, derby db

```
 <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100" value="#{markingBean.spinnerNumber1}" 
                                               stepFactor = "1"  min="80" max="100" disabled = "#{formBean.number != 8}">  
                                        <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                                    </p:spinner> 

    <p:commandButton action="#{markingBean.markSectionOne}" value="#{bundle.buttonSave}" update=":growl" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

Above is how the user selects the value and it is then passed to a bean :

```
public void markSectionOne() {
        this.markToCreate.create(this.markToCreate);
    }
```

however it looks like this is the reason for the error

```
public void create(Marking markToCreate) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

i have found that code on the bottom on my Marking entity class,

the question i have is how can i insert the value from the spinner into my table marking under markSectionOne column ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need an intermediary between the UI and the database.  You should never think about it as "spinner into my table" or any other UI element.

Do it in steps:

1. Get the UI form POST to the intermediary.  Validate and bind the incoming data.
2. Process the incoming data and persist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would i do this imtermedairy step ?

Comment: jsf is one of many java web mvc frameworks out there.  your pages should be sending requests to the front controller, which passes them on to action/handler classes.

Comment: That is already happening; that markSectionOne() is a method in a backing bean. And then some code is called which isn't implemented yet, and things don't work. Not very strange. What IS strange is that the actual persistence method (create()) is inside an Entity class. I don't know who are what created this code, but they're "uninformed".